# What kind class can be treated as strong typed model in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In visual studio, i right click view folder and open "**add view**" dialog, then i choose **strongly-typed model**, but i found **NOT** every class under model folder will be shown in the dropdownList.

My question is: Why other model classes aren't shown there? What kind of class have the right to be treated as strongly-typed model?

Comment: Just to check - have you tried rebuilding your solution first? The drop-down only get's re-populated after a build so if you have added a class, you will need to build before it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any class as view model that you have defined and is part of your project. Make sure you have built your project so that classes in the Models folder get picked-up by the Visual Studio UI. Or simply type the name of the class in the textbox instead of relying on the dropdown.